# Getting a filename from a http web request/response

Tags: python, web

I'm currently working on a web scraping project and working on how to determine the "best" file name for saving a file locally. I see a few options in determining what to name the file - scrape it from the url request (assuming a valid file name can be extracted), grab it from the response header, content-disposition filename if it's set, some custom header data that the web server returns, etc. Every site seems to return data slightly differently and it makes it very difficult to determine how to name file locally.

I've done some searching and I haven't seen any code that handles the situation of requests/responses data in determining a "best" filename. Hoping someone may have a more robust algorithm to help deal with this issue so I don't have to code it from scratch.

I've scraped the websites and got the responses. However, I'm looking for an efficient method of naming the files received from a web server.

Comment: What is the purpose of file naming? Is it to avoid conflicts, to have human-readable names, or to make it easier for other programs to use? If a DB is included in the project, after writing the file-related information in record, the file name is simply set as uuid, and later it can be found by DB search.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.